# Scrollable SideBar Upto a certain div

Tags: jquery

My question is that i have a sidebar that remains fix when i scroll the screen down.
But I have some hidden div as well, which is opened when i click on their name and want that the scroll should go till the footer with the open div and with the close div as well.

Hope you would help me in this.
Here's the code for the above

**css**

```
body {
        margin: 10px auto;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 500px;
    }

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
}

#sidebarWrap {
    height: 400px;
    width: 210px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    width: 270px;
    height: 2000px;
}

#small {
    width: 270px;
    height: 400px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

#header {
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sidebar.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}


#footer { height: 600px; }
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#small').hide();
            $('p').click(function() {
                $('#small').toggle();

            });
        });
        $(function() {
        var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
        var footTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

        var maxY = footTop - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (y > top) {
                if (y < maxY) {
                    $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
                } else {
                    $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: (maxY - top) + 'px'
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
```

**html**

```
<div id="sidebarWrap">
        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        Main
    </div>

    <p>Small</p>

    <div id="small">
        Small
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5Uh69/ It uses pure CSS to give a sidebar 100% height and its own scroll...

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```